# Find specific string in excel, copy the specific string and copy to new cell in same row

Tags: string, excel, vba, extract

I am a not experienced in programming in VBA or python, though learning. 
I have an excel file that contains a very specific string `ab/c/defg/0123/456` within a string of variable length (text & numeric). The variable string is always locate in the subject header of the email. for purposes I have extracted this to excel.

What i want to accomplish is the find the string `ab/c/defg/0123/456` in the excel file and copy that specific string to a empty cell in the same row in the same excel of course. If the string is not found the cell will be left empty. To make it more complex the string may also appear as `ab/c/defg/**123**/456` or the back slashes are forward slashes.

in excel the function split, MID, left, right aren't helpful as the string may appear at random within the string: something like the following:

row1: ab/c/defg/0123/456 blablalbla 03/10/2012 - 05/11/2012 - blablabla. 
row2: blablalbla 04/10/2012 - 01/11/2012 - blablabla blablabla,blablabla blablabla ab/c/defg/0123/456.
row3: blablalbla ab/c/defg/0123/456 blablabla 
row4: blablalbla 13/10/2012 - blablabla 
row5:  blablalbla; blablabla blablablablablabla blablabla ab/c/defg/0123/456 - blablabla 1234456

result would be:
                                       c                                              d
row1: ab/c/defg/0123/456 blablalbla 03/10/2012 - 05/11/2012 - blablabla.      ab/c/defg/0123/456
etc....
row 4 column d would than be no value/empty

the file contains approx. 9000 rows, but may be larger when analysis a different mailbox/excel file.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Is the string always the same combination of alphanumeric characters, or can any letter go where you have put 'a', and any number where you have put '2'?

Comment: Welcome to SO! We don't write code for you, but we help you if you have a problem with your code. So have a go, and if you need help ask us specifically what the problem is later.

Comment: Kaybee99, your completely right any letter can go where "a" Placed and same for "2"that can be any number.

Answer (score 0):

First, and possibly the best idea is to use `Range.Find` method. It will both give you information if the string was found and return the range/cell where string was found (if so). What I warn you about- be careful with additional parameters which `.Find` method possibly do not require but it seems that you will finally have to use them.

Here is [link to method description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839746%28v=office.14%29.aspx). Examples which you will find there are very useful. 
Additionally check `.Range.FindNext` property too.

You could make some experiences with macro recorder as it fully support `.Find` features.

If you finally know where is your finding result in the sheet, in which cell, you could quite easily get to any cell within the row, eg. first empty cell when looking from the right you get in this way:

```
Dim rngFound as Range 
'if rngFound represent cell where is your string
'then first free cell from the right:
Dim rngFreeThisRow as Range
Set rngFreeThisRow = Cells(rngFound.Row, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0,1)
```

Remarks to slashes and backslashes. You would possibly need to fire you searching few times and each time you will have to change 'data to search for', eg.:

1. at the first step you could search for `ab/c/defg/123/456` (for exact match)
2. if not found at next step you could search for `Replace("ab/c/defg/123/456". "/", "\")`
3. but it would be possibly better, if there is any kind of pattern in your string, to use substitution marks like `*` and `?`, eg. `ab?c?defg?123?456` or  `ab?c?defg?*123?456`
4. and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply KazJAw, I will try to test this weekend.